# When ${\mathbb{R}}^X$ is a multiplication $C(X)$-module?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $X$ be a compact P-space (i.e., any prime ideal of the ring of continuous functions $C(X)$ on $X$ is a maximal ideal of $C(X)$.). Is ${\mathbb{R}}^X$ a multiplication $C(X)$-module?
Recall that an $R$-module $M$ is an $R$-module if any submodule of $M$ has the form $IM$ for some ideal $I$ of $R$.

Comment: "Recall that an $R$-module $M$ is an $R$-module if..." you mean "is a *multiplication* $R$-module if..."

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).